# Select date for a column value after using DATE_ADD in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've subscription start date in my table. I want to alert my customers about subscription gonna end(between 10 months and 1 year is my subscriber's alert period)

This is my Query:

```
SELECT customer_name, start_date
FROM subscription
WHERE start_date between DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
and DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 305 DAY)
```

I tried hours, nothing workout. Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Shouldn't you subtract? This would work if that would be expiration date not start date. And you cannot compare date with date - 1year. It makes no sense. `SELECT * FROM subscription WHERE start_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 305 DAY)`

Comment: How can start_date be between 2 dates which are both added to start_date? This will return 0 results. 

SELECT customer_name, start_date FROM subscription WHERE stop_date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 305 DAYS) AND DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR);

Answer (score 0):

The operands to `BETWEEN` need to be in order.  So, the smaller value needs to be first:

```
SELECT customer_name, start_date
FROM subscription
WHERE start_date between DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 305 DAY) and
                         DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

305 days is less than one year, so that needs to go first.

Answer (score 0):

When you use **between** on SQL Query for two values, you have to add less one to your query first.

```
SELECT customer_name, start_date FROM subscription 
WHERE start_date between DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 305 DAY) and DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

did you try this Query?

Comment: This query is not wrong. Try to execute it on your SQL Manager and check if it gives the right answers. If not you have to check your table, values, value types. If it gives right rows, so you have to check your programming code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you record `start_date` of the subscription and you want to figure out the subscriptions that are 10 to 1 year old **today**, you need the `start_date` be between 1 year from now and 10 months from now.

```
SELECT 
   customer_name, 
   start_date
FROM subscription
WHERE start_date BETWEEN 
   DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND
   DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 305 DAY)
```